# Eager Loading Relationships with Yajra Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Everyone hello, first thing I want to do is to show the data from the hotels table attached to the rooms table to the single listing page.

I am getting this error

> Exception Message:Call to undefined method App\Hotel::map()

**RoomController.php**

```
public function apiRoom() {
    $hotels = Room::with('hotel');
    return Datatables::eloquent($hotels)
        ->addColumn('hotel', function (Room $htl) {
            return $htl->hotel->map(function ($hotellist) {
                    return str_limit($hotellist->hotel_name);
                });
        });

    $rooms = Room::all();
    return Datatables::of($rooms)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($rooms) {
            return '<a onclick="editForm('.$rooms->id.')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i> </a>'.
            '<a onclick="deleteData('.$rooms->id.')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Close"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> </a>';

        })->make(true);
```

**room-list.blade.php**

```
var table = $('#room-table').DataTable({
                      processing: true,
                      serverSide: true,
                      ajax: "{{ route('api.room') }}",
                      columns: [
                        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                        {data: 'hotel', name: 'hotel.hotel_name'},
                        {data: 'room_name', name: 'room_name'},
                        {data: 'bonus_sum', name: 'bonus_sum'},
                        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                      ]
                    });
```

Model File Room.php

```
class Room extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable   = ['hotel_id', 'room_name', 'bonus_sum'];
    public function Hotel() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel', 'hotel_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Room` belongs to only one `Hotel`. Therefore, `$htl->hotel` is a single object, not a collection, and you can't call `map()` on it.